# Laggy graphics in Gnome Desktop on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 18.04, beta

Right now I am running the release version of Ubuntu 18.04 but for some reason gnome desktop seems to remain ever so lagging and unusable. It is so bad that even the scrolling lags.

This thing fortunately/Unfortunately (depends on how you see it) is unique to gnome desktop so other desktops *cough* Budgie *cough* remain un-laagy and thankfully usable. However is there any way to get rid of this frustrating lag in Gnome.

My PC Specs:

- Intel dh61bf motherboard
- gt710 (gk208) GPU
- Intel core i3 processor.
- 500 GB HDD of which 55.5 GB to Ubuntu and rest to Windows

Comment: Which core i3 processor? Are you using the iGPU on it? Are you using the nVidia GPU, if so the Nouveau or nVidia proprietary drivers? If using the nVidia GPU I'd suggest using the Intel iGPU for comparison.

Comment: I am using the nonproprietary driver

Comment: Can you run this command in the terminal and copy the results into your question? `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"`

Comment: `OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon (TM) Pro WX Series (POLARIS11, DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-29-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)` (and other stuff: https://gist.github.com/khatchad/93533192b4ea89eb67bd0ef8d217bb45)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the "non-proprietary" driver. You are using the nVidia driver 390.48. In the terminal type:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Then reboot and the Intel iGPU will be used and hopefully performance will be better.

Comment: The thing is I was using noveau before but switched to nvidia after you commented on the question. There is an improvement in performance but it is really marginal

Comment: Thank you very much @WinEunuuchs2Unix, this solved the problem for me!

Comment: @BenSower You're welcome. You can upvote any question or answer you find helpful in **Ask Ubuntu** by clicking the up arrow next to it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Already did, apparently not everyone is as greatful as I am :-P

Comment: `sudo: prime-select: command not found`